Python3: ZIP file as input to cgi script
What I'm trying to do: I want to send a ZIP file to a Python 3 CGI script over the web. Not as a form, just a payload with Content-Type application/zip that I can extract a relevant file from and process with pandas.
# [... import statements left out ...]

archive = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
df = pd.read_xml(
    zipfile.ZipFile.open(archive,"apple_health_export/export.xml"),
    xpath="//Record[contains(@type,'HKQuantity')]",
    attrs_only=True
)

If I use sys.stdin.read(), I get 'str' object has no attribute 'fp'; if I use sys.stdin.buffer.read(), I get 'bytes' object has no attribute 'fp', both errors at the pd.read_xml() statement.

It looks like you’ve summarized the explanation about the trailing slash (/) in Python function parameter lists very well! Here’s a cleaned-up version of your summary, maintaining the core details:
Positional-Only Parameters in Python
The trailing slash (/) in a Python function’s parameter list, as seen in the documentation (e.g., str.removeprefix(prefix, /)), indicates that the parameters before the slash are positional-only. This means these arguments must be passed by position and cannot be passed as keyword arguments.
Why Use Positional-Only Parameters?
1.  Simplicity:
•   It prevents ambiguity by ensuring the function is called in a straightforward manner.
2.  Performance:
•   Positional arguments are slightly more efficient to handle than keyword arguments.
3.  Compatibility:
•   Restricting to positional-only arguments can help ensure the function’s implementation can evolve without breaking existing code that uses keyword arguments.

Examples of Positional-Only Parameters
Example 1: str.removeprefix
The method str.removeprefix() from the Python standard library shows the use of positional-only parameters.
help(str.removeprefix)
The output shows:
removeprefix(self, prefix, /)
•   The / indicates that the prefix argument must be passed positionally.

Correct Usage:
"unittest".removeprefix("unit")
Incorrect Usage:
"unittest".removeprefix(prefix="unit")  # Raises a TypeError
Example 2: Defining a Custom Function with Positional-Only Parameters
In Python 3.8 and later, you can define functions with positional-only parameters using the / syntax:
def add(x, y, /):
return x + y
•   x and y are positional-only parameters.

Correct Usage:
add(3, 5)
Incorrect Usage:
add(x=3, y=5)  # Raises TypeError: add() takes no keyword arguments
General Syntax
In a function definition:
•   Parameters before the / are positional-only.
•   Parameters after the / (if any) can be either positional or keyword arguments.
For example:
def func(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd_only):
...
Here:
1.  pos1 and pos2 are positional-only.
2.  pos_or_kwd can be passed either as a positional or keyword argument.
3.  kwd_only is a keyword-only argument (indicated by the *).
Summary
When you see a / in the function signature in Python’s documentation, it signifies that the parameters before it are positional-only. This helps make the function call syntax clearer, avoids ambiguity, and ensures the function is used as intended without confusion over keyword arguments. It’s also useful for enhancing performance and backward compatibility.
I hope this clarifies how the / notation works in Python. Let me know if you need further clarification!

This answer makes absolutely no sense to the question. In any event, I ended up switching to webhook instead, which lets me POST with a raw file.
